# Alternative to using 'in' with numpy.where()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Lets say I have an array, 'foo', with two columns. Column 0 has values 1 to 12 indicating months. Column 1 has the corresponding measurement values. If I wanted to create a mask of measurement values from December, January and February (12,1,2) I would suspect that I could:

```
numpy.where(foo[:,1] in (12, 1, 2), False, True)
```

But it would appear that my clever 'in (12, 1, 2)' doesn't work as a conditional for where(). Nor does it appear to work as [12, 1, 2], etc...

Is there another clever way to do this? Is there a better way for me to collect all of the (12, 1, 2) measurements into an array? What is the numpy way?

(Reshaping the array is out of the question because there are an irregular number of measurements for each month)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason the 'in (12, 1, 2)' does not work is that the element before the 'in' has to be a single element.

But for this, numpy has the function `in1d` ([documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)) to do a 'in' with a numpy array. With your code:

```
np.where(np.in1d(foo[:,0], [12, 1, 2]), False, True)
```

---

To complete the answer with the comment: in this case using `where` is redundant, the output of `in1d` can be used to index foo:

```
foo[np.in1d(foo[:,0], [12, 1, 2])]
```

or for

```
foo[~np.in1d(foo[:,0], [12, 1, 2])]
```

Note: `in1d` is only available from numpy 1.4 or higher.

Comment: Yeah! I don't even need the np.where() with this! I can create what I need just using np.in1d()
Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, the output of np.in1d can be used to index foo.